# How to integrate c++ classes and objects around winApi?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, qt, integration

Hey so for one of my c++ projects I need to develop a 4-5 window application.Now the issue is that currently all of my programs tasks are divided into classes, and I have tested them by passing 'dummy' values and returning print results. That's all fine and working, however now as I want to introduce a GUI interface it presents me with the problem of how my processing should communicate with the front end, since winAPI is initially meant for c and not object oriented language.

What I am thinking of doing, and have a feeling is going to be a tedious task, to make a class which does the win api's registrations and methods for me. Is there any other alternative to this ???

I was looking at integrating Qt into eclipse but I think they stopped providing the library for eclipse, because I couldn't find a download for the library anywhere, not even on the Qt download page.

Comment: if (Qt) { use (QtCreator); }
else if(MS) { use(VisualStudio); }
else { go(theHardWay, useEclipse & WinAPI); }

Comment: lol yes I wish the first condition would equal true...however like I mentioned don't think the library is available any more and besides I'm looking for open source stuff and QtCreator I believe needs to be purchased

Comment: nop, QTCreator is free as a bird! Just download: http://qt.digia.com/product/developer-tools/

Comment: Really but why does it then mention "Ready to purchase" ?? sorry I'm a bit confused ??

Comment: If you want and you are ready .. you can purchase :) And you will get support from them... Otherwise just download, install, use and you're on your own developing your code :) More accurate download location: http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/qtcreator/ and for the SDK: http://qt-project.org/downloads ...

Comment: Hey but do I need both or can I manage with only creator ??

Comment: WTL; even under partial-dev, still better than Win32 API, and one helluva lot less bulk than others. I still used it to slam out one-off GUIs

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use Win32, then you have to do all the stuff that Win32 needs you to do. It's a rather low level API, so you just have to take care of a lot of details.

However, don't over-engineer things. You don't have to write a generic C++ wrapper for Win32... you just have to make a GUI for your program.

Comment: there are people who would argue a generic C++ wrapper for WinAPI is called MFC :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only that classes are not supported by C, then simply **replace the keyword** `class` **with the keyword** `struct`. Just make sure to **declare the access types of all variables** (private, public, protected), that way it becomes interchangeable (Works for both). The **only difference between them is the default access type**, which **for classes is private**.  In case you used other syntax that is unique to C++, then this wouldn't work.

There are code generators from C++ to C as well. The optimal solution would be to create a GUI using an IDE specifically for that purpose which uses C++ as its base language. MFC works well, but it is not open-source and you will need a considerable knowledge on inheritance and comfort with "class typecasting". Using the included wizards in Visual Studio will help.

Try the first option; it will possibly work the same way.

Comment: Yes I considered that, but requirement:
1- Choose a OOP language in which you are comfortable and have adequate experience with, hence you can depict each class into diagrams to show the interactions. 
Advice best to separate front-end and back-end processing (as well as other relevant functionalities) into meaningful and re-usable classes.